# Suppose $[G : H] = p$ and $[G : K] = q$ for two distinct primes $p$ and $q$. Compute a formula for $|H \cap K|$ in terms of $p$ ,$q$ and $|G|$.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $[G : H] = p$ and $[G : K] = q$ for two distinct primes $p$ and $q$. Compute a formula for $|H \cap K|$ in terms of $p$ ,$q$ and $|G|$.

**My Attempt**

So given the Lagrange Theorem, $|G| = |H| \cdot p$ and $|G| = |K|\cdot q$

Then I considered using the given relation which I proved myself:

$|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ which can be re-arranged to give

$|H\cap K|=\frac{|H||K|}{|HK|}$ where $|H|=\frac{|G|}{p}$ and $|K|=\frac{|G|}{q}$.

Firstly is this method ok for this question? and if so do I continue by defining $|HK|$ in terms of $p$ ,$q$ and $|G|$ and just sub in to the above equation.

If anyone has any better methods please share them if you can. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $H,K$ have relatively prime indices then $G=HK$. Try to prove yourself or see for example [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Corollary X.12. Hence $|H \cap K|=\frac{|G|}{pq}$.

Comment: OK. Thanks Nicky

Comment: You are welcome! See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467188/proving-that-pq-divides-g-h-cap-k?rq=1

Comment: @GavinK14 Please, if you deem my answer the right one, tick the answer in that it gets a green tick, being the policy here at StackExchange. Thanks and keep posting questions and answers!